# How to update a table without changing the onscreen data displayed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to display a simple list of hundreds of items which are on a MySQL table, review the list onscreen and click on a link beside each unwanted item to delete it from the table. This is an internal management procedure; no outside user is involved. I do not need the item to disappear from the list immediately; I will refresh the list periodically so items deleted from the table are no longer listed. I do not need any message to confirm that the item has been deleted. The important thing is that I don't want to lose sight of the list each time I delete an item and have to click on a "go back" button to return to the list.

The table uses MySQL. All my coding to date has been in PHP. So I am using php to display the list of items, on a non-html screen. This is the code for each item:

```
echo $item." <a href='item_delete.php?id=".$item."'>Delete item</a><br />";
```

This is the code for item_delete.php:

```
<?php
require ('connect.php');    //  To define connection $con
$id = $_POST['id'];
mysqli_query($con, "DELETE FROM `items_table` WHERE `id` = $id");
?>
```

The item is deleted correctly but a blank screen is (understandably) displayed.

I have done a lot of searching but most people needing help want to do more advanced things and - because I have so far managed to avoid learning JavaScript, jQuery and AJAX - I can't even work out which of those technologies I need to update a table without changing the screen.

I get the impression that each PHP script always takes "focus" with it, so maybe I need a little JavaScript script to do this ?
If so: 
- can I just change item_delete.php to item_delete.js or do I have to define the non-html list as an html one ?
- what js code is needed in item_delete.js ?

I have read about using: header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
or: header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
but they don't go back to the onscreen list.

I don't think I want the js script to perform a virtual "go back" because the list is originally produced by using (about 20) $_POST parameters, so I still seem to have to refresh it each time.

So I'd like a solution to remain with the list - rather than leave it and return to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It would make a lot of sense to do the deletion asynchronously using javascript. However, the simplest and messiest way to achieve what you want, is to add target="_blank" to the links, (which will leave you with a open blank tab for each delete request you do).

```
echo $item." <a href='item_delete.php?id=".$item."'       target='_blank'>Delete item</a><br />";
```

Or you can solve it by adding checkboxes in front of every item, check the items you want to delete and submit them as form parameters to the delete script.

Comment: Many thanks Erikzy. Yes, I will have to adopt the checkboxes solution if I need to use my existing skillset ! I'll see if someone has a quick js solution first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete to row in the onscreen table after the actual PHP code has run you can use the following implementation:

The HTML structure for the link requires a unique class name, such as:

```
echo '<a href="" onclick="return false" class="item-delete" data-item-id="' . $item . '">Delete item</a>'
```

Note the item id is stored inside a HTML5 [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attribute. I have also added an `onclick` event handler which returns `false` to avoid the link refreshing the page.

The javascript used to delete the item use the JQuery AJAX method and binds to the specified class, which is: `item-delete`. The implementation requires Jquery version >= 1.9.0

```
(function(){

    $('.item-delete').click(function(event) {
        var target = $(event.target);
        var id     = target.data('item-id');

        $.ajax({
           url: 'item_delete.php',
           method: 'POST',
           data: {
               id: id
           },
        }).done(function() {
            target.remove();
        }).error(function(err) {
            console.error('Could not delete item with ID: ' + id);
            console.error(err);
        });
    });    

}())
```

The event listener is defined inside a self-executing function, which is automatically executed when the page-load completes and avoids poluting the global namespace.

Comment: Many thanks. I'm afraid I now realize that I need to learn some JavaScript before I can even assess - let alone implement - your solution. So - if there is no easy shortcut - you have done me a service and I will come back to your solution when I have learned the basics. As I tried (but maybe failed) to explain, I don't need to "delete a row in the onscreen table"; I only need to delete a row in the MySQL table. Thanks again.

Comment: @user607229 I am glad to hear you are taking your time to understand the code before implementing it and highly encourage that way of engaging code. For your reference, if you wanted to not delete the row, you would remove the part after the `$.ajax({...})` which says: `.done(function() {...})`. Feel free to ask if the code needs clarification.

Comment: Thanks AnotherGuy.  Much appreciated. I now feel a bit closer to understanding it and will report any success but it'll be a few days !

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the item directly on the same page without moving to another
page by passing the id through a hyperlink and then get it to finally delete 
the unwanted item. CHECK THIS OUT, and please let me whether or not is what you
   wanted :-)

```
 // connection 
 mysql_connect("host", "user", "password");
 mysql_select_db("your database name");


 // select all the items from table.

 $selectQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_name" );

 // use while loop to list all the items...

 while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($selectQuery) )
 {
 // list the items as a hyperlink, passing their id through the URL.
 ?>  
    <a href ="?id=<?php echo $row["id"];?>"> <?php echo "delete " .              $row["item_name"];  ?>  </a>

 <?php       
 } 
 // Below is the code to delete the item.

 if( isset( $_GET["id"] ) )
  { 
    $itemId = $_GET["id"]; 

   // query to delete item

   $deleteQuery  = mysql_query("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = '$itemId'       "); 
      //-----------THE MOST IMPORTANT PART. >>>
      // redirect if delete is successfull.

     if( $deleteQuery )
      {    
         // reload the page to get the items minus the deleted one...
         // let's say your sript name is delete.php      

             header("Location:delete.php");
          } 
        } 
         ?>

        </code>
```

Comment: Thanks Andis but when the delete query runs, it moves to another page and doesn't redirect back to the page (because that page was originally created using 20 $_POST parameters). I want to delete without moving from (or changing) the page with the list of items.